# Running yarn add <package_name> after running a yarn install relinks all of the dependencies

Tags: yarnpkg

I removed the node_modules folder, and I ran a `yarn install` command to get a fresh build. This took a very long time, as yarn went through the process of linking all of dependencies for the first time.

Right after, I ran `yarn add html2canvas`. yarn went through the whole process of linking all of the dependencies again, which takes another ~30 minutes.

Why would installing 1 package trigger this lengthy build process? How can I make sure that it doesn't go through linking all the dependencies, and only execute for the one I'm installing?